# How to encrypt hosting URL (API) which created in php using in android app code

Tags: java, php, android, api, security

I want to encrypt plain text URLs in a text file which is embedded in an Android APK. I am currently saving my URLs in as Strings in that file. With these URLs I am loading data from a MySQL database. The structure is as follows:

```
String url="http://faazani.com"/api
```

However, I want to encrypt the URL while using it. If someone extracted these URLs from the APK file, they would know where we host the API. I want to keep this a secret.

As this is a serious issue for me, I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

There's very little reason to encrypt a URL for an Android App

Anyone can decompile your app and see what you're doing to decrypt it, if they wanted, which is the least of your worries, since anyone can usually setup a debugging proxy and watch the traffic from your app go to your server and back, and see the URL.

Your web API needs to have security controls, if someone simply knowing your URL is a concern for security, you've already got problems, independent of the android app.